# Initializing a Vector (C++)

Tags: c++, vector

I've been trying to create a function that takes in numbers into a vector (7 to be exact), and computes the average. However, I have tried initialising each vector element to a number entered by the user. Example:

```
double average(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g)
vector<double>aa;
aa[0]=int a;
aa[1]=int b;
aa[2]=int c; etc.
```

But when I do that, I get

> error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’

When I change it to

```
for(size_t j=0; j<=7; j++)
{
    cout<<"Enter item # " <<(j+1);
    cin>>a[j];
}
```

I get

> invalid types ‘int[size_t {aka unsigned int}]’ for array subscript
>      cin>>a[j];

I am new to programming, and may not understand complex answers.
I do apologize if this question has been asked before. I use Linux Ubuntu to compile my code (Terminal, g++).

N.B. Our lecturer's answer for this was:

```
double average (const vector<int>& v)
{
    int N = v.size();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i = i + 1)
    {
        sum = sum + v[i];
    }
    return static_cast<double>(sum)/(N); 
}
```

(I think mine is wrong since he asked for "call by reference function" and I think I created a "call by value". I have a no idea what he wrote (especially the `return static_cast<double>(sum)/(N);`.

Comment: So you had a problem statement and your lecturer supplied a correct solution. What exactly is your question?

Comment: His answer confused me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really should pick up your textbook, and start reading, preferably yesterday. Nevertheless, I'll address to each section separately.

Your code (changed slightly)

```
double average(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g)
{
    vector<double>aa;
    aa[0]=int a;
    aa[1]=int b;
    aa[2]=int c;
    // etc.
}
```

Has a few problems. The error you received was due to all the lines that looked like `aa[0]=int a;` The word `int` is not supposed to be there. If you remove them, it should compile, and crash on runtime, as `aa` still has a size of 0. You can either preallocate the vector (`vector<double> aa(7);`) or use `aa.push_back(aa);`.

In your second attempt

```
for(size_t j=0; j<=7; j++)
{
    cout<<"Enter item # " <<(j+1);
    cin>>a[j];
}
```

For starters, the first line should be `for(size_t j=0; j<7; j++)` (missing the `=`). `a` should be the `vector<double>` from the first attempt, and not the function argument.

Your lecturers code has the line

```
double average (const vector<int>& v)
```

The `&` before the `v` tells the function that it's not receiving a copy (by value) of the variable `v`, but rather the original copy (by reference). Often, that means that if the function changes its value, then the calling functions copy is changed. Here, however, there is that magical word `const` that disallows the function from changing the value(s).

Lastly, the `static_cast<double>` is a form of casting (changing) the variable type from an `int` to a `double`. The reason for this is that `3/2 == 1` whereas `3.0/2 == 1.5`.

Answer (score 0):

`const vector<int>& v` -> This says that pass a vector whose elements are of type `int` by a `const` reference i.e. you cannot change `v` (add/delete/insert/resize)

The `for` part is the for loop, that loops from `0` to `v.size()-1` i.e. array indexing in C++ starts from 0 and so does indexing for vectors. Hence the first element is v[0], so on...

`sum = sum + v[i]` -> This performs the summation of all the elements of v.

Finally, you need to divide by the number of elements in v in order to calculate the average. But dividing a `int` by an `std::size_t` wont give you a result with the decimal places. Hence you need to cast the values to `double`.

Hence `static_cast<double>(sum)/(N)`.

As for initializing a `std::vector`, use something like this :

```
std::vector<int> v ;
int temp = 0 ;
while(true) {
    std::cin >> temp ;
    if(temp == -1)
        break ;
    v.push_back(temp);
}
```

The above code will read input and insert into vector till -1 is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the errors from the compiler in the code

```
vector<double>aa;
aa[0]=int a;
aa[1]=int b;
aa[2]=int c;
```

is the presence of the `int` keyword in each of the assignments.   Remove them.

The other problem that the compiler will not complain about is that a vector is created with size `0` by default.  The next problem is that `vector`'s `operator[]` (called by the expression `aa[0]`, etc) does not magically resize the vector as needed.   If the index is invalid, the behaviour is undefined.

It is therefore necessary to size the vector before trying to assign its elements.

```
vector<double>aa (some_integer_greater_than_2);
aa[0]=a;
aa[1]=b;
aa[2]=c;
```

or

```
vector<double>aa;
aa.resize(some_integer_greater_than_2)
aa[0]=a;
aa[1]=b;
aa[2]=c;
```

If you don't know the size of the vector in advance, use `push_back()` (which adds an element to the end, resizing as needed).

```
vector<double>aa;
aa.push_back(a);    //since initial size is zero, this (in effect) resizes and copies a to aa[0]
aa.push_back(b);    //since size is now 1, this (in effect) resizes and copies b to aa[1]
aa.push_back(c);    //since size is now 2, this (in effect) resizes and copies c to aa[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a rank beginner, but having just emerged from one of those prolonged "why in the name of all that is good and oily doesn't this work" moments trying to input integers into a vector of defined maximum size, I offer this note.  My error was that in defining the maximum size of my vector -- vector numbs(25) -- I inadvertently used brackets instead of parens -- i.e., vector numbs[25] -- with the unhappy effect of getting the most perplexing failure at the input stage -- i.e., cin >> numbs[i].  Here is the subject code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int size, i;
    vector<int> numbs(25); //error was using brackets instead of parens
    cout << "Please enter the size of the vector you wish to create (<25)";      
    cin >> size; 
    cout << "Please enter " << size << " integers: ";
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
        cin >> numbs[i];  // where the effect of the prior error showed up
    return 0;
}
```